# Проблема с тригерами SQLite

Tags: sqlite3, sqlite, sql

У меня возникла такая проблема. Я пытаюсь добавить в таблицу информацию. Но браузер выдаёт ошибку

> "No Data Received"

Пользуюсь SQLite. Вставка примитивная:

```
$db->exec("INSERT INTO mapseasy VALUES ('TEST2', 'TEST', '1234')");
```

Тут же открываю эту базу данных через Менеджер SQLite и добавляю вручную - всё замечательно. Я думаю, что проблема в том, что у меня имеются несколько тригеров. И именно они (AFTER INSERT) что-то блокируют либо прерывают... Я несколько часов пробовал различные варианты, ничего не помогает. И ещё в каталоге, где находится база данных, создаётся файл с расширением .sqlite-journal. Проходит минуты 2, файл удаляется, браузер возвращает пустую страницу.

Я думаю, что этот файл создаётся, когда в БД посылается очень сложный запрос? Но у меня запрос примитивный, и время на выполнение тригеров на ПК тратится очень мало, может быть, на сервер стоит какое-нибудь ограничение?
Буду благодарен, если подскажете что-нибудь. Спасибо.

Ребят, я ещё почитал. Пишут, что SQLite блокирует базу для одного пользователя. То есть получается, что я делаю запрос с сайта (php файл), а тригеры исполняются от имени пользователя системы? Может быть, поэтому возникает конфликт какой-нибудь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В запросе не перечислены поля, которые вставляются, должно быть так:

```
INSERT INTO mapseasy (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('TEST2', 'TEST', '1234');
```

Comment: Нет, не в этом дело...

Comment: Если не в этом, то гадание на кофейной гуще... Или выкладывать нужно все триггеры, чтобы можно было найти причину, хотя дело вряд ли в них, т.к. они бы срабатывали и при ручной вставке

Comment: Я разобрался. Тему можно закрывать. Проблема в многопользовательском доступе к файлу базы данных.